# Showing $i_*:\pi_k(X^n, x_0) \to \pi_k(X, x_0)$ is injective for $k \le n-1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I've got a question about the solution of the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a connected CW-complex and $X^n$ its $n$-skeleton (i.e. the subcomplex of all cells of dimension $n$ or less). Denote by $i\colon X^n \to
>  X$ the inclusion and let $x_0 \in X^n$ be any base point. Show that
>    $i_*\colon \pi_k(X^n, x_0) \to \pi_k(X, x_0)$ is injective for $k \le n-1$.

The solution says right at the beginning:

> Suppose that $k \le n-1$ and $[f] \in \pi_k(X^n, x_0)$ lies in the
>    kernel of $i_*$. First of all we may assume $f$ is cellular. There is a base point preserving homotopy $H:S^k\times [0,1]\to X$ from $f$ to the constant map.

**My questions:**

1) Why is there a base point preserving homotopy from $f$ to the constant map? I struggle to see why $f$ is nullhomotopic.

2) We've chosen $[f] \in \pi_k(X^n, x_0)$, thus $f$ is a map given by $$f\colon S^k \to X^n.$$ The homotopy $H$ however seems to start at $h_0 = f\colon S^k \to X$ which would represent an element of $\pi_k(X,x_0)$ rather than $\pi_k(X^n, x_0)$. Or is this still valid since $X^n \subseteq X$?

Appreciating any help!

Thank you very much.

Comment: By cellular approximation, and since $S^k \times I$ is a k+1 dimensional comlex, you can always assume that up to homotopy $H:S^k \times I \to X$ factors through the n-th skeleton

Comment: And regarding your first question, this is just by the assumption that $f$ lies in the kernel of $i_*$

Comment: thank you E.KOW, but picking an arbitrary element of the kernel and showing it is homotopic to the constant map is precisely what we aim to prove, isn't it?

Comment: No, what you want to prove is that an element in the kernel, i.e. nullhomotopic in $X$, will be zero also in $\pi_*\left(X_n, x_0 \right)$, i.e. nullhomotopic also in $X_n$, which means exactly that the nullhomotopy in $X$ can be chosen to have an image in $X_n$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. So when we are talking about $f \in \pi_k(X^n,x_0)$ being nullhomotopic in $X$, we actually mean the image $[i\circ f] \in \pi_k(X,x_0)$, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, when we talk about maps between the topological spaces we regard maps to $X^n$ as maps to $X$, because $i$ is injective, in contrast with $i_*$ which is in general not injective.

Comment: thank you very much E.KOW, highly appreciating your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the solution is worded a bit strangely.

We are concerned with the injectivity of the map $i_*\colon \pi_k(X^n) \to \pi_k(X)$, so if we assume $[f]\in \pi_k(X^n)$ is in the kernel of $i_*$ then by definition there is a basepoint-preserving homotopy from $i\circ f\colon S^k \to X$ to the constant map. (We could consider $f$ and $i\circ f$ to be "the same" since $i$ is an inclusion, but they are technically different.)

The question now is whether or not $[f] = 0$ i.e. whether there is a basepoint preserving nullhomotopy of $f\colon S^k \to X^n$. But suppose $H\colon S^k \times [0,1] \to X$ is a basepoint-preserving homotopy from $i\circ f$ to the constant map. If we assume that $f$ is cellular then $H$ is already cellular on the subcomplex $K = S^k \times \{0\} \cup \{e_1\} \times I$, then by cellular approximation $H$ is homotopic to a cellular map $\tilde{H}\colon S^k\times [0,1] \to X$ which agrees with $H$ on $K$. But since $k \leq n-1$ and $dim(S^k\times [0,1]) = k + 1$ it follows by cellularity that the image of $\tilde{H}$ is actually in $X^n$, or in other words it is a basepoint-preserving nullhomotopy of $f$ in $X^n$ so $[f] = 0 \in \pi_k(X^n)$.

Comment: beautiful, thank you William. That was quite helpful indeed.